# Replace an object in a List<Object> when Object is a List? Java

Tags: java, list, object

Hello again stackoverflow,
I have a question concerning List of Objects.

I have tried out writing some things, but can't find it though.
How do I find an Object in a list of objects, when these objects are lists of its own?

this is what i have so far:

Recipe is a List of: {modification[], ingredients[], recipeBookName, recipeName}

```
public void removeFromBook(Recipe recipeName) {
    recipes = getRecipes();
    emptyRecipe = getEmptyPage(recipeBookName);
```

Now, I want to replace a Recipe which has a recipeName, by the emptyRecipe.
I think it will be something like:

```
for(r in recipes) {
    if(r.recipeName == recipeName) {
        list.replace(Recipe, emptyRecipe)
    } else {

    }
}
```

any ideas? :)

here's my constructor for the Recipe class:

```
    public String[] modifications;
public String[] ingredients;
public String recipeName;
public String partOfRecipeBook;

public Recipe(String recipeName, String[] modifications, String[] ingredients, String recipeBookName){
    setRecipeModifications(modifications);
    setRecipeIngredients(ingredients);
    setRecipeName(recipeName);
    setRecipeBookName(recipeBookName);
}
```

Comment: So you have a `List<List<Object>>`, and each `List<Object>` is a `Recipe` list? Using `List<Object>` isn't really taking advantage of generics at all. Can you show us a little more code (like how you add objects to the list, what objects you make, etc.)

Comment: It seems that you're using the word *List* not like a java programmer would expect. You don't mean a `java.util.List`, do you?

Comment: What is the type of `recipes`?

Comment: `Recipe is a List of: {modification[], ingredients[], recipeBookName, recipeName}` that does not sound right. I don't think you should use a list for storing the different things, but define your own class which has dedicated members for the modifications, ingredients and so on

Comment: eum, hold on lemme search my code :)

Comment: My understanding is that he has a `List<Recipe>`, where `Recipe` is a class that contains several members: `modification[], ingredients[], recipeBookName, recipeName`.

Comment: Just a style comment: You really don't need that empty else clause.

Comment: oh man, I'm far far away from a real Java programmer, I wish to be one in the future though :) I just hope the amount of "facepalms" you guys are giving yourselves right now isn't too high, I'm really still learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a List with Objects in it (of which some are arrays) is not the best way it would be better to define a new object Recipe and use that.

```
public class Recipe {
    private List<Ingredient> ingredients;
    private List<Modification> modifications;
    private String bookName;
    private String book;
}
```

Then replacing in ingredients is a lot simpler. e.g. give recipe a function like

```
public void replaceIngredent(Ingredient oldIngredient, Ingredient newIngredient) {
    int index = ingredients.indexOf(oldIngredient);
    if (index != -1) {
        ingredients.remove(index);
        ingredients.add(index, newIngredient);
    }
}
```

Comment: True, I should get some more coffee and a break, I'm really messing up my things.. too much coding :) thank you

Comment: sorry replaceItem does not exist.

Comment: @DavidVandenbroucke, if you do use a class Ingredient instead of a String, then remember to implement an equals function (this is used by indexOf).

Comment: This one did the trick eventually :) changed the green V :)
Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Your approach looks fine, except that you should compare strings with equals:

```
if(r.recipeName.equals(recipeName)) {
```

Now an even easier way would be to store your recipes in a Map:

```
Map<String, Recipe> recipes = new HashMap<String, Recipe>();
recipes.put("Pizza with Lobster", new Recipe());
```

when you want to replace a recipe:

```
recipes.put("Pizza with Lobster", emptyRecipe);
```

and the old recipe has been replaced.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private List<TimeModel> timeModels = new ArrayList<TimeModel>();
```

then you simply put

```
  timeModels.set(0, new TimeModel("6:00 PM"));
```

and after that set `yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).